# Client side HTTPS redirecting issue

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm having temperamental HTTP to HTTPS client side redirections, say if I enter example.com and www.example.com for most of the part they both redirect to https://www.example.com but on the odd occasion I run into cors issues and it doesn't redirect to HTTPS. I'm using next js for server-side rendering if that has any effect on why I'm experiencing this problem? Here is my code I am using

```
const httpsRedirect = async () => {
      const loaded = await window.document
      if(loaded) {
        let httpTokens = /^http:\/\/(.*)$/.exec(window.location.href);
        if(httpTokens) { 
          window.location.replace('https://' + httpTokens[1]);
        }
      }
}
httpsRedirect()
```

Comment: Why not do this with server side configuration? P.s. if you don't tell us exactly what errors you get, or have some idea what the pattern might be of when it happens, it's pretty difficult to help

Comment: `const loaded = await window.document` what's goin on here? is that some next.js magic?

Comment: @ADyson I've tried to do this via server side but I was having more issues trying to implement a redirect on the backend using GraphQL Yoga rather than express.
I can't pinpoint exactly what is going wrong, but if the browser doesn't detect an https href, it refreshes and redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. It's quite random but 1 out of 5 times entering www.example.com it fails to redirect to an ssl connection and cors jumps in and page just continually refreshes. I can fix this by manually refreshing myself. I asume this is something to do with my loaded check.

Comment: @KevinB From what I understand it's the same as writing
if (window.document) {
let httpTokens = /^http:\/\/(.*)$/.exec(window.location.href);
        if(httpTokens) { 
          window.location.replace('https://' + httpTokens[1]);
        }
}

Comment: Again, exactly what error do you get when this happens?